# React - Best case approach to use useEffect as a simple trigger

Tags: reactjs, triggers

I have a parent component that contains two children: `Editor` and `Table`.
Editor Component allows the user to insert a text and save it to the database. Table Component shows every text in the database.
Table has `edit` and `delete` buttons for each row. When `edit` is pressed, the row information is displayed inside the editor and the editor allows to update changes. (So far, pretty normal CRUD I'd say).

I'm willing to use a variable in the parent so when a content is updated, the table (that is loaded using fetch) is re-loaded with the updated content, calling `fetch` inside `useEffect`, which is triggered by a `useState` called `[Reload,setReload]` on the parent.

My question is, how can I trigger this `useEffect` "under demand" properly? I can create a counter and every time it is +1 it changes, so `useEffect` is triggered. But this is probably not the right approach. I also tried passing both Reload and setReload to the children to create a boolean that when any row is edited: `setReload(!Reload)`, initialized by `useState(false)`, but this is not triggering the table update.

I wonder what's the best approach for this case.

*(Simplified Code)*

Parent Component

```
export default function Parent() {
const [reload,setReload] = useState(false);
return (<div><Editor reloadTable={setReload}/>
<Table reloadFetch={reload} setReloadFetch={setReload}/></div>);
}
```

Editor component

```
export default function Editor({reloadTable}){
const edit= ()=>{
return fetcher(url).then(reloadTable(true));
}
```

Table component

```
export default function Table({reloadFetch,setReloadFetch}) {
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)... //fetch code, this is what is not happening when setting `reloadTable(true)` in Editor Component.
}, [reloadFetch]);
}
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding you right, on every edit you are making you wanna re-fetch the data and re-render the table component ?

Comment: Exactly, my question is what's the best approach for the dependency array since a boolean that is set as the contrary of its value does not trigger it.

Comment: Make it either null or Math.random/a counter. It could be any  unique value, but this one is dead simple and can be debugged if needed, this would be harder with empty object, etc

Comment: You can just edit the data array that the table is using to render every time you finish  editing a row. That way you don't have to fetch new data from api.

Comment: @EstusFlask I think these are workarounds and does not answer the question. I don't think Math.Random is the right approach to change a value of something so useEffect is triggered. (I may be wrong though, but I feel like that's not the right way).

Comment: It's fairly ok for this case. Use uuid or a counter if you want it to look more "solid" (no real benefits though). As it was mentioned, it makes sense to update data in the first place to trigger the update, but this shouldn't be used only as a workaround. Btw could be done the opposite way,there's useImperativeHandle to expose Table reload method to a parent instead

Comment: What you can do is manage a state in your table component, and every time you make an edit the state will be changed and hence component will be re-rendered and henceforth useEffect will be triggered. pass the state as dependency to useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably only a workaround and not the cleanest solution, but you could use `Date.now()` like:

```
const [lastFetchedAt, setLastFetchedAt] = useState(Date.now());
```

Then you can put `lastFetchedAt` in useEffect dependency array and then:

```
<Table refetch={() => setLastFetchedAt(Date.now()} />
```